# look for a free flv player

Tags: video, flv, flvplayer

In our application,we save some flv data in the oracle data using the blob type.

Now we want to display these videos in the web page,since we want the video can be played across browser,so we want to use something like flash.

I have googled,and found the flowplayer is pretty good,however it is not in our consideration because:

1)there are some logos in the free version.

2)The most important,the flowplayer and some plugin(the playlist plugin) is built based the jQuery, and in our page we have used the prototype1.4,so we do not want to use two different lib at the same time for avoiding the conflict problem.

We just have the following requirements:

*1) it can support the video stream rather than a flv file.*'

I mean our video is saved in the db, when we retrieve it,we get the binary stream,it would be find if we do not need to transform it as a real xx.flv file.

*2)It would be better if the player do not user some third part lib which may cause conflict problem*

*3)Support playlist.*

Since we may have several video parts for one object,for example,for a building,we may have 3 video to display it. So it would be better if the player support playlist(for example,there is a "next video","prev video" in the controls of the player.

*4)lightweight.*

Any suggestion?

Comment: If your application is commercial for which you're charging users, you're better off buying something rather than using a freely available player. Also, why don't you consider native videos using HTML5 rather than rely on a flash based player?

Comment: Our site is not commerical use,it will be userd only by our department. Also,the reason I do not use the html5 video tag is that I have to support the old browser,for example,the IE6.\

Comment: If it will only be used by your department, then the branding problem is not an issue is it? Also, you *can* include jquery only in the page which presents the video. It's a small library and won't really cause any "conflict" problem.

Comment: branding problem is not an issue is it? :( in fact,it is,and I have to support the old browser. I have a page used to play the video,but there are also a number of pages which use the prototype and I have put some video inside of.

Comment: If you don't want branding, you should be willing to pay. You're getting a high quality cross platform video player for free, you should be willing to at the very least let them advertise their player. As for jquery, I don't think it's a problem. You should include it and see if it really creates a problem. If so, consider something else.

Comment: Sorry,I saw the branding as browser,yes,you are right,the branding(the logo) is not a big problem. For the jquery,I have tested add the jquery in the page which user the prototype,it does not work.

Comment: I add the jquery.js at last(in the head),then test code is simple:(function($) { $(document).ready(function(){alert("jquery")}); })(jQuery) But I do not see the alert window

Comment: Try using something like firebug to see if the library is getting loaded properly.

Comment: Yes,it has been loaded(I see itin the network panel of the firebug)>

Comment: I can't really debug your app remotely but getting jquery to load up shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.! Now it works using the jQuery.noConflict()! Thanks. Can you make a replay to my question,then I accept it as my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want branding, you should be willing to pay. You're getting a high quality cross platform video player for free, you should be willing to at the very least let them advertise their player. As for jquery, I don't think it's a problem. You should include it and see if it really creates a problem. If so, consider something else.